# Preserving the order of records from subquery while using "Union distinct" construct

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, union

I want to make sure that the order of the result from subquery are preserved while using Union distinct. Please note that "union distinct" is required to filter on duplicates while doing the union.

For example:

```
select columnA1, columnA2 from tableA order by [columnA3] asc
union distinct
select columnB1, columnB2 from tableB
```

When I run this, I am expecting that the records ordered from subquery ( select `columnA1`, `columnA2` from `tableA` sort by `[columnA3]` asc) comes in first (as returned by order by `columnA3` asc) followed by those from `tableB`.

I am assuming that I cannot add another dummy column because that would make union distinct to not work. So, this won't work:

```
select column1, column2 from 
 ( select column1, column2, 1 as ORD from tableA order by [columnA3] asc
 union distinct
 select column1, column2, 2 as ORD from tableB 
 ) order by ORD
```

Comment: Why can't you add a dummy column? What is wrong with it?

Comment: @Karolis The uniqueness of records from tableA and tableB is established based on the pair {column1. column2}. Adding a dummy column (to ensure the order) makes them non-unique.

Comment: Yeah, I understood what you are trying to do from Cade's answer :)

Answer (score 6):

Essentially, MySQL isn’t preserving the order of records from sub-query while using “Union distinct” construct. After a bit of research, I found that it works if we put in a limit clause or have nested queries. So, below are the two approaches:

Approach-1: Use Limit clause

```
         select columnA1, columnA2 from tableA order by [columnA3] asc Limit 100000000
         union distinct
         select columnB1, columnB2 from tableB
```

I have tested this behavior using few datasets and it seems to work consistently. Also, there is a reference to this behavior in MySQL‘s documentation ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/union.html ):
 “Use of ORDER BY for individual SELECT statements implies nothing about the order in which the rows appear in the final result because UNION by default produces an unordered set of rows. Therefore, the use of ORDER BY in this context is typically in conjunction with LIMIT, so that it is used to determine the subset of the selected rows to retrieve for the SELECT, even though it does not necessarily affect the order of those rows in the final UNION result. If ORDER BY appears without LIMIT in a SELECT, it is optimized away because it will have no effect anyway.”

Please note that there is no particular reason in choosing LIMIT of 10000000000 other than having a sufficiently high number to make sure we cover all cases.

Approach-2:   A nested query like the one below also works.

```
        select column1, column2 from 
        ( select column1, column2 order by [columnA3] asc ) alias1
        union distinct
        ( select column1, column2 from tableB )
```

I couldn’t find a reason for nested query to work. There have being some references online (like the one from Phil McCarley at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html ) but no official documentation from MySQL.

Comment: You helped a fella 10 years in the future! The limit on each subquery solved my problem.

Comment: Another happy fella here! Great trick, saved me a lot of headache.

Answer (score 1):

```
select column1, column2 from 
 ( select column1, column2, 1 as ORD from tableA
 union distinct
 select tableB.column1, tableB.column2, 2 as ORD from tableB 
  LEFT JOIN tableA
      ON tableA.column1 = tableB.column1 AND tableA.column2 = tableB.column2
  WHERE tableA.column1 IS NULL
 ) order by ORD
```

note that UNION not only de-dupes across the separate sets, but within sets

Alternatively:

```
select column1, column2 from 
 ( select column1, column2, 1 as ORD from tableA
 union distinct
 select column1, column2, 2 as ORD from tableB 
 WHERE (column1, column2) NOT IN (SELECT column1, column2 from tableA)
 ) order by ORD
```

Comment: `order by` inside union has no sense, you have to put it outside of union.

Comment: @Karolis - sorry, that came in from his example.

Comment: @CadeRoux - Unfortunately I cannot do a left join because the other table is huge and is causing a performance bottleneck. Infact, that was my first approach but it is too slow.

Comment: @user965692 Then I don't see how the first example runs reasonably in the first place.  Isn't the table indexed?

Comment: @user965692 With huge table a **dependent** `NOT EXISTS` subquery should work faster, but then a **composite** index on (column1, column2) is needed.

Comment: @Karolis UNION DISTINCT effective requires a sort - seems to me that if the table is huge (what does that mean?) it probably should be indexed in the first place.  I would think even a partial index on column1 would help, but I'd have to see the execution plan and more about the real problem the OP is trying to solve.