# Wordpress combine queries

Tags: php, mysql, post, wordpress

I have two queries that I need to try to combine so that my pagination works correctly, and the posts show up in the correct order.

I have this one query:

```
$today = date('m/d/Y', strtotime('today'));

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'workshops',
    "posts_per_page" => 5,
    "paged" => $paged,
    'meta_key' => 'select_dates_0_workshop_date',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                  'key' => 'select_dates_0_workshop_date',
                  'meta-value' => "meta_value",
                  'value' => $today,
                  'compare' => '>=',
                  'type' => 'CHAR'
             )
    )
    );
```

The results of this query need to come after the query above:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'workshops',
    "posts_per_page" => 5,
    "paged" => $paged,
    'meta_key' => 'select_dates_0_workshop_date',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'DESC',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                 'key' => 'select_dates_0_workshop_date',
                 'meta-value' => "meta_value",
                 'value' => $today,
                 'compare' => '<',
                 'type' => 'CHAR'
        )
    )
    );
```

The difference between the two queries is the: `'order'` and the `'compare'`.

I have done this in pure MYSQL Queries, but I am not sure how to do this on WordPress

Comment: If it was me, I'd start with a view - and just query on that.

Comment: This question is interesting and I'd like to answer you, but I didn't fully understood your requirements, so if you help me understand better I can help you. I see you're fetching future workshops and past workshops in two separate queries, but I don't understand how you want to display them. Is it a mix of the two driven by the same impagination (from what I understood), is it two different post loops with different pagination but in the same page or is something else you want to achieve?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*This is an updated version of the answer, that's more flexible then the previous one.*

Here's one idea using a SQL `UNION`:

- We can use the data from the `posts_clauses` filter to rewrite the SQL query from the `posts_request` filter.
- We extend the `WP_Query` class to achieve our goal. We actually do that twice:

  - `WP_Query_Empty`: to get the generated SQL query of each sub-queries, but without doing the database query.
  - `WP_Query_Combine`: to fetch the posts.
- The following implementation supports combining `N` sub-queries.

Here are two demos:

### Demo #1:

Let's assume you have six posts, ordered by date (DESC):

```
CCC
AAA
BBB
CCC
YYY
ZZZ
XXX
```

where the `XXX`, `YYY` and `ZZZ` are older than  `DT=2013-12-14 13:03:40`.

Let's order our posts so that posts published after `DT` are ordered by title (ASC) and posts publisehd before `DT` are ordered by title (DESC):

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
ZZZ
YYY
XXX
```

Then we can use the following:

```
/**
 * Demo #1 - Combine two sub queries:
 */

$args1 = array(
    'post_type'  => 'post',
    'orderby'    => 'title',
    'order'      => 'ASC',
    'date_query' => array(
        array( 'after' => '2013-12-14 13:03:40' ),
    ),
);

$args2 = array(
    'post_type'  => 'post',
    'orderby'    => 'title',
    'order'      => 'DESC',
    'date_query' => array(
        array( 'before' => '2013-12-14 13:03:40', 'inclusive' => TRUE ),    
    ),
);

$args = array( 
   'posts_per_page' => 1,
   'paged'          => 1,
   'sublimit'       => 1000,
   'args'           => array( $args1, $args2 ),
);

$results = new WP_Combine_Queries( $args );
```

This generates the following SQL query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM ( 
    ( SELECT wp_posts.* 
        FROM wp_posts 
        WHERE 1=1 
            AND ( ( post_date > '2013-12-14 13:03:40' ) ) 
            AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' 
            AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') 
            ORDER BY wp_posts.post_title ASC 
            LIMIT 1000
    ) 
    UNION 
    ( SELECT wp_posts.* 
        FROM wp_posts 
        WHERE 1=1 
        AND ( ( post_date <= '2013-12-14 13:03:40' ) ) 
        AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' 
        AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') 
        ORDER BY wp_posts.post_title DESC 
        LIMIT 1000
    ) 
) as combined LIMIT 0, 10
```

### Demo #2:

Here's your example:

```
/**
 * Demo #2 - Combine two sub queries:
 */

$today = date( 'm/d/Y', strtotime( 'today' ) );

$args1 = array(
    'post_type'      => 'workshops',
    'meta_key'       => 'select_dates_0_workshop_date',
    'orderby'        => 'meta_value',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'meta_query'     => array(
        array(
            'key'         => 'select_dates_0_workshop_date',
            'value'       => $today,
            'compare'     => '>=',
            'type'        => 'CHAR',
        ),
    )
);

$args2 = array(
    'post_type'      => 'workshops',
    'meta_key'       => 'select_dates_0_workshop_date',
    'orderby'        => 'meta_value',
    'order'          => 'DESC',
    'meta_query'     => array(
        array(
            'key'         => 'select_dates_0_workshop_date',
            'value'       => $today,
            'compare'     => '<',
            'type'        => 'CHAR',
        ),
    )
);

$args = array( 
   'posts_per_page' => 5,
   'paged'          => 4,
   'sublimit'       => 1000,
   'args'           => array( $args1, $args2 ),
);

$results = new WP_Combine_Queries( $args );
```

This should give you a query like this one:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM ( 
    ( SELECT wp_posts.* 
        FROM wp_posts 
        INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id) 
        INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id) 
        WHERE 1=1 
            AND wp_posts.post_type = 'workshops' 
            AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_author = 1 AND wp_posts.post_status = 'private') 
            AND (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'select_dates_0_workshop_date' AND (mt1.meta_key = 'select_dates_0_workshop_date' AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS CHAR) >= '05/16/2014') ) 
            GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
            ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value ASC
            LIMIT 1000 
        ) 
    UNION 
    ( SELECT wp_posts.* 
        FROM wp_posts 
        INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id) 
        INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id) 
        WHERE 1=1 
            AND wp_posts.post_type = 'workshops' 
            AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_author = 1 AND wp_posts.post_status = 'private') 
            AND (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'select_dates_0_workshop_date' AND (mt1.meta_key = 'select_dates_0_workshop_date' AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS CHAR) < '05/16/2014') ) 
            GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
            ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value DESC 
            LIMIT 1000 
        ) 
) as combined LIMIT 15, 5
```

### Demo #3:

We could also combine more than two sub queries:

```
/**
 * Demo #3 - Combine four sub queries:
 */

$args = array( 
   'posts_per_page' => 10,
   'paged'          => 1,
   'sublimit'       => 1000,
   'args'           => array( $args1, $args2, $args3, $args4 ),
);

$results = new WP_Combine_Queries( $args );
```

### Classes:

Here are our demo classes:

```
/**
 * Class WP_Combine_Queries
 * 
 * @uses WP_Query_Empty
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/a/23704088/2078474
 *
 */

class WP_Combine_Queries extends WP_Query 
{
    protected $args    = array();
    protected $sub_sql = array();
    protected $sql     = '';

    public function __construct( $args = array() )
    {
        $defaults = array(
            'sublimit'       => 1000,
            'posts_per_page' => 10,
            'paged'          => 1,
            'args'           => array(),
        );

        $this->args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );

        add_filter( 'posts_request',  array( $this, 'posts_request' ), PHP_INT_MAX  );

        parent::__construct( array( 'post_type' => 'post' ) );
    }

    public function posts_request( $request )
    {
        remove_filter( current_filter(), array( $this, __FUNCTION__ ), PHP_INT_MAX  );

        // Collect the generated SQL for each sub-query:
        foreach( (array) $this->args['args'] as $a )
        {
            $q = new WP_Query_Empty( $a, $this->args['sublimit'] );
            $this->sub_sql[] = $q->get_sql();
            unset( $q );
        }

        // Combine all the sub-queries into a single SQL query.
        // We must have at least two subqueries:
        if ( count( $this->sub_sql ) > 1 )
        {
            $s = '(' . join( ') UNION (', $this->sub_sql ) . ' ) ';

            $request = sprintf( "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM ( $s ) as combined LIMIT %s,%s",
                $this->args['posts_per_page'] * ( $this->args['paged']-1 ),
                $this->args['posts_per_page']
            );          
        }
        return $request;
    }

} // end class

/**
 * Class WP_Query_Empty
 *
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/a/23704088/2078474
 */

class WP_Query_Empty extends WP_Query 
{
    protected $args      = array();
    protected $sql       = '';
    protected $limits    = '';
    protected $sublimit  = 0;

    public function __construct( $args = array(), $sublimit = 1000 )
    {
        $this->args     = $args;
        $this->sublimit = $sublimit;

        add_filter( 'posts_clauses',  array( $this, 'posts_clauses' ), PHP_INT_MAX  );
        add_filter( 'posts_request',  array( $this, 'posts_request' ), PHP_INT_MAX  );

        parent::__construct( $args );
    }

    public function posts_request( $request )
    {
        remove_filter( current_filter(), array( $this, __FUNCTION__ ), PHP_INT_MAX );
        $this->sql = $this->modify( $request );             
        return '';
    }

    public function posts_clauses( $clauses )
    {
        remove_filter( current_filter(), array( $this, __FUNCTION__ ), PHP_INT_MAX  );
        $this->limits = $clauses['limits'];
        return $clauses;
    }

    protected function modify( $request )
    {
        $request = str_ireplace( 'SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS', '', $request );

        if( $this->sublimit > 0 )
            return str_ireplace( $this->limits, sprintf( 'LIMIT %d', $this->sublimit ), $request );
        else
            return $request;
    }

   public function get_sql( )
    {
        return $this->sql;
    }

} // end class
```

You can then adjust the classes to your needs.

I use the trick [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7587423/2078474) to preserve the order of `UNION` sub queries. 
You can modify it accordingly with our `sublimit` parameter.

This should also work for **main queries**, by using the `posts_request` filter, for example.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much! But I'm not really sure how to adjust my queries to work with this?

Comment: Hi @DylanCross, I updated the answer with some demos, that you can hopefully play with.

Comment: I will post a another implementation (by extending the WP_Query class) of this idea later today, that will be easier to work with.

Comment: Holy cow, this is deep stuff dude, awesome! @DylanCross, hope you don't let the bounty end without awarding it (and let the other answer receive 50% as it has more votes), btw, how does it come you haven't +1 at least? ('cause the actual one is mine;)

Comment: @brasofilo thanks, it just expanded out of my hands, I wasn't planning  have it so long, sorry about that ;-) I hope you guys can extend this further and fix the errors. Hopefully I can take this to github at the end of the month, when things get less busy here. I would like to use **dependency injection** instead of hardcoding one of the classes inside the other class. I also need to test this more to better understand the limitations. But hey, this is just for fun -   a playground of curiosity ;-)

Comment: where to add this sql ?

Comment: @NishamMahsin I added this to GitHub as a plugin, see [here](https://github.com/birgire/wp-combine-queries).

Comment: Just want to add a new comment to say that @birgire 's GitHub plugin is (relatively) recently updated and has 4 total contributors, so definitely grab the code from https://github.com/birgire/wp-combine-queries instead of from this comment.

Answer (score 3):

The trouble lies in the 'order' argument: the 'meta_query' argument [accepts an array of meta queries](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) as well as the 'relation' argument (basically, "AND" or "OR"). This could be used to select posts both less-than and greater-than-or-equal-to `$today` (though at that point the meta query is useless as it's selecting every ("OR") or no ("AND") workshops. Unfortunately, WP_Query doesn't allow you to arbitrarily sort results (switching from closest upcoming to most recent past workshop).

If you know how to pull this off directly in MySQL, you might consider looking at [the WP_Query filters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Filters), specifically the [`posts_orderby` filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_orderby). These filters enable you to start playing with the actual SQL being generated by the WP_Query class without having to switch to totally-custom queries. Be forewarned, however, that it's important to limit the scope of these filters or risk them being applied to *every* query on your site (the [`posts_where` filter documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_where) has some good examples on how to do so).

Answer (score 1):

```
$now = gmdate( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );

$u_webinars = new WP_Query( array(
    'fields'                => 'ids',
    'post_type'             => 'webinars',
    'meta_key'              => 'start_end_date_%_xtk_start_date',
    'posts_per_page'        => -1,
    'orderby'               => 'meta_value',
    'order'                 => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array( // phpcs:ignore WordPress.DB.SlowDBQuery.slow_db_query_meta_query
        array(
            'key'       => 'start_end_date_%_xtk_end_date',
            'compare'   => '>',
            'value'     => $now,
            'type'      => 'DATETIME'
        )
    )
) );

$p_webinars = new WP_Query( array(
    'fields'            => 'ids',
    'post_type'         => 'webinars',
    'meta_key'          => 'start_end_date_%_xtk_start_date',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
    'order'             => 'DESC',
    'meta_query' => array( // phpcs:ignore WordPress.DB.SlowDBQuery.slow_db_query_meta_query
        array(
            'key'       => 'start_end_date_%_xtk_end_date',
            'compare'   => '<',
            'value'     => $now,
            'type'      => 'DATETIME'
        )
    )
) );

$all_ids_arr = array_merge( $u_webinars->posts, $p_webinars->posts );

$page_number = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$all_webinars = new WP_Query( array( 
        'post__in'          => $all_ids_arr, 
        'posts_per_page'    => 16,
        'paged'             => $page_number,
        'post_type'         => 'webinars',
        'orderby'           => 'post__in'
    ) 
); 

// Loop will be written here
```